# Display Email of the logged in user in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone please advise how do we display the EmailID of the logged-in user in a View. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 identity.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Could someone please reply to my question ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the user's email as the username then once the user has already been authenticated you can access the name from the User Principal  `Identity.Name`

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {

    <span>@User.Identity.Name</span>

}
```

That is the simple approach. If you did not use the email as the username then you will have to attach that info using claims and then you can use an extenion method to retrieve it. I had the reverse problem. I stored the email as the username and needed to get the logged-in user's Full Name to display. I then had to do what I described for you and had to add a custom `DisplayName()` extension for the `IIdentity` .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the **`@inject`** feature call for injecting both `UserManager` and `SignInManager` (This feature available in .NET Core).

**In your view add the following:**

```
@inject SignInManager<YourUserIdentity> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<YourUserIdentity> UserManager
```

After the injection, you should be able to work with `UserManager` and `SignInManager` methods. For instance:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)</a>
}
else
{
}
```

> Pay attention for passing the `User` object when you need to reference the current logged in user.

In your case, if you would like to get the logged in Email Address, you can use the following technique:

```
var loggedInUserName = @UserManager.GetUserName(User);

var loggedInEmail = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(
        UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == loggedInUserName)
        );
```

Or just keep it inside a ViewBag as you like. 
Hope this will be handy for anyone :)